# Compile Error Visual studio 2013

Tags: c++

Hi I have problems with compiling this code. I got an error and I don't know how to fix it. I searched on Google but I found nothing.

player.h : http://wklej.org/id/1639093/
player.cpp http://wklej.org/id/1639094/

```
   1>------ Build started: Project: tibiafun, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  player.cpp
1>  Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
1>c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\definitions.h(25): warning C4005: 'EWOULDBLOCK' : macro redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\errno.h(132) : see previous definition of 'EWOULDBLOCK'
1>c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\fileloader.h(269): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\creature.h(294): warning C4101: 'vipstatus' : unreferenced local variable
1>c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\player.h(545): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'editedHouseRights'
1>c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\player.h(545): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\player.h(547): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'rights_t'
1>c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\player.h(368): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>player.cpp(125): error C2065: 'editedHouseRights' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(125): error C2065: 'HOUSE_NONE' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(278): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
1>player.cpp(299): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
1>player.cpp(303): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
1>player.cpp(309): error C2059: syntax error : 'switch'
1>player.cpp(310): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>player.cpp(310): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>player.cpp(325): error C2059: syntax error : 'if'
1>player.cpp(326): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>player.cpp(326): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>player.cpp(354): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<<'
1>player.cpp(354): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>player.cpp(354): error C2059: syntax error : 'string'
1>player.cpp(354): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>player.cpp(354): error C2365: 'exit' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdlib.h(376) : see declaration of 'exit'
1>player.cpp(357): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>player.cpp(357): error C2365: 'str' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
1>player.cpp(357): error C2228: left of '.str' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'int'
1>player.cpp(358): error C2059: syntax error : 'return'
1>player.cpp(359): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>player.cpp(359): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>player.cpp(362): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>player.cpp(362): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>player.cpp(417): warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'double' to 'int32_t', possible loss of data
1>player.cpp(444): warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'double' to 'int32_t', possible loss of data
1>player.cpp(1237): error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'playervoc_t' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>player.cpp(1237): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
1>player.cpp(1244): error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'playervoc_t' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>player.cpp(1250): error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'playervoc_t' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>player.cpp(1389): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'uint64_t' to 'int32_t', possible loss of data
1>player.cpp(1533): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>player.cpp(2156): warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'uint64_t' to 'int32_t', possible loss of data
1>player.cpp(2161): warning C4244: '-=' : conversion from 'uint64_t' to 'int32_t', possible loss of data
1>player.cpp(2180): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
1>player.cpp(2181): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
1>player.cpp(2182): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
1>player.cpp(2183): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
1>player.cpp(2184): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
1>player.cpp(2225): warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'uint64_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
1>player.cpp(2237): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>player.cpp(2245): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'uint64_t' to 'int32_t', possible loss of data
1>player.cpp(2265): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>player.cpp(2335): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
1>player.cpp(2340): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
1>player.cpp(2345): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
1>player.cpp(2878): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'rights_t'
1>player.cpp(2885): error C2065: 'editedHouseRights' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2885): error C2065: 'rights' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2888): error C2065: 'rights' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2888): error C2065: 'HOUSE_OWNER' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2889): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2889): error C2227: left of '->getOwner' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2894): error C2065: 'rights' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2894): error C2065: 'HOUSE_SUBOWNER' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2895): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2895): error C2227: left of '->getSubOwners' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2896): error C2065: 'rights' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2896): error C2065: 'HOUSE_DOOROWNER' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2897): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2897): error C2227: left of '->getDoorOwners' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2898): error C2065: 'rights' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2898): error C2065: 'HOUSE_GUEST' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2899): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2899): error C2227: left of '->getGuests' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2913): error C2065: 'editedHouseRights' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2913): error C2065: 'HOUSE_GUEST' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2915): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2915): error C2227: left of '->getGuests' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2916): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2916): error C2227: left of '->setGuests' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2925): error C2065: 'editedHouseRights' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2925): error C2065: 'HOUSE_DOOROWNER' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2927): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2927): error C2227: left of '->getDoorOwners' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2928): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2928): error C2227: left of '->setDoorOwners' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2930): error C2065: 'editedHouseRights' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2930): error C2065: 'HOUSE_SUBOWNER' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2932): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2932): error C2227: left of '->getSubOwners' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2933): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2933): error C2227: left of '->setSubOwners' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2935): error C2065: 'editedHouseRights' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2935): error C2065: 'HOUSE_OWNER' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2937): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2937): error C2227: left of '->getOwner' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2938): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2938): error C2227: left of '->setOwner' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2955): error C2039: 'getHouse' : is not a member of 'Tile'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(19) : see declaration of 'Tile'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(19) : see declaration of 'Tile'
1>player.cpp(2955): error C2227: left of '->getPlayerRights' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2955): error C2065: 'HOUSE_NONE' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2956): error C2039: 'getHouse' : is not a member of 'Tile'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(19) : see declaration of 'Tile'
1>player.cpp(2956): error C2227: left of '->getFrontDoor' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2956): error C2660: 'Game::teleport' : function does not take 1 arguments
1>player.cpp(2964): error C2039: 'getHouse' : is not a member of 'Tile'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(19) : see declaration of 'Tile'
1>player.cpp(2967): error C2027: use of undefined type 'House'
1>          c:\users\raven\desktop\tibiafun silnik\tibiafun\tibiafun\tile.h(12) : see declaration of 'House'
1>player.cpp(2967): error C2227: left of '->save' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>player.cpp(2976): error C2065: 'editedHouseRights' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(2976): error C2065: 'HOUSE_NONE' : undeclared identifier
1>player.cpp(3474): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 4 arguments
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========





else if (editedHouseRights == HOUSE_DOOROWNER)
{
    membersBefore = editedHouse->getDoorOwners(editedHousePos);
    editedHouse->setDoorOwners(membersAfter, editedHousePos);
}
else if (editedHouseRights == HOUSE_SUBOWNER)
{
    membersBefore = editedHouse->getSubOwners();
    editedHouse->setSubOwners(membersAfter);
}
else if (editedHouseRights == HOUSE_OWNER)
{
    membersBefore = editedHouse->getOwner();
    editedHouse->setOwner(membersAfter);
}

      s <<"\nReputation: "<<(access>0?"+":"")<<access<<"\n";exit(1);

          s <<"\nReputation: "<<(access>0?"+":"")<<access<<"\n";exit(1);
#endif //_BDD_REPUTACJA_

    str = s.str();
    return str;
   }

Item* Player::getItem(int32_t pos) const
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing an include. At leas the type rights_t is not known by the compiler.

Comment: @MartinSchlott how i can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It is nearly impossible to answer the question without knowing the whole project. I guess you downloaded from somewhere. The error you are facing is a symptom not the cause. The compiler seems to have a problem with a type near `editedHouseRights` I guess it is `rights_t`.

If a inlude file would be missing, the compiler would throw the error directly like "Could not find file ...." but in this case it didn't. With that knowledge there can only be three errors be left.

1. You are missing a library the project expect to be in place. Read the installation manual. You may missing something.
2. The code uses #ifdef switches. Maybe you forgot to set a right #define. That should also be found in a documentation.
3. Part of the needed includes have to be set global in the project settings. Read the manual for that.

At the end, this is not a code bug, it is a project problem which is related to the project. Ask someone from the project.